# Load a PHP file as a CSS file from the plugin webroot folder

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3

How can I execute a PHP file to generate CSS, and place that file in my plugins webroot folder.

For example;

/app/plugins/myplugin/webroot/css/style.php

If I place the style.php file in the applications webroot folder, then it works fine. When I move the PHP file to the plugin's webroot it doesn't load. I get a CakePHP error saying that the CssController doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont put it in the webroot, just make an action of a controller render the css.

This is an example doing a similar thing, `JS` in this case..

[controller](https://github.com/Infinitas-Plugins/InfinitasPiwik/blob/master/Controller/InfinitasPiwikController.php#L8) and [view](https://github.com/Infinitas-Plugins/InfinitasPiwik/blob/master/View/InfinitasPiwik/js/tracker.ctp)

The route for that is `/infinitas_piwik/infinitas_piwik/tracker.js` by default, although it is easy to use the router to change it to pretty much anything.